# Upgrading DataNucleus DB engine (Neodatis) to latest version generates ClassCastException

Tags: java, datanucleus, classcastexception

I'm running DataNucleus with NeoDatis as the data store.

The version that DataNucleus ships is 1.9, I'd like to upgrade to 1.9.30 (due to some odd exceptions I'm debugging in NeoDatis).

When I swap out the NeoDatis jar file that came with DataNucleus with the current one from NeoDatis I get a class cast exception on `org.neodatis.odb.core.query.AbstactQuery`.

But that class clearly exists in the updated jar file, Eclipse finds it for auto complete. I'm darn sure it's in the classpath.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `ClassCastException` does not arise from a missing class (that's what `NoClassDefFoundError` is for); instead, it's thrown because the code attempted to cast an object to an incompatible type.

In this instance, it means the new version of NeoDatis is not completely backward-compatible with the version you had.

Do you have a full stacktrace for the `ClassCastException`? I'll update this with some concrete answers after I study the stacktrace. :-)

Comment: Oh Genius of Genius, you're right! I did get that backwards didn't I? That takes me down a whole other path of inquiry. Ok, thanks for setting me straight, I'll track down the problem in that new light and go from there. This is exactly what I needed. I'll post other questions if I can't work out the problems myself first.